# Must every magnetic configuration have a north and south pole?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

Magnets have a magnetic north and south pole. Solenoids too have north and south pole from which magnetic fields comes out and goes in respectively. But is it that every magnetic configuration have a north and south pole? Electrons have magnetic moment and they can be regarded as very tiny magnets. So, where is its north and south pole?

Comment: Let me check my supply of monopoles. I used most of them up in the last hyperspace jump. :-) .  But, yeah, check the literature on electron spin orientation.

Answer (score 2):

You van have [two pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_magnet) of north/south if you wish.

Comment: To clarify, you can have an arrangement of magnets, such as the one found in the link, that has no magnetic moment. In this case you can't sensibly say that the arrangement of magnets has a north a south pole.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the absence of magnetic monopoles, every magnet must have a north and south pole.

Comment: What about the case of electrons that I mentioned?

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR electrons can not really be "regarded as very tiny magnets." Electrons can not be regarded as anything but quantum particles. Trying to compare electrons to objects won't get you anywhere.