# Why do Magnetic North and South Poles never exist by themselves?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

As the title suggest, whilst I was reading I saw written that a '**Magnetic North or South Pole has never been found by itself**'. And I was wondering why this was?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Must every magnetic configuration have a north and south pole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86657/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric forces that we see in nature are due to separate charges (electric monopole charge), however, all matter ever isolated to date, including every atom on the periodic table and every particle in the standard model, has zero magnetic monopole charge. Therefore, the ordinary phenomena of magnetism and magnets have nothing to do with magnetic monopoles.
Instead, magnetism in ordinary matter comes from two sources. First, electric currents create magnetic fields according to Ampère's law. Second, many elementary particles have an "intrinsic" magnetic moment, the most important of which is the electron magnetic dipole moment; this magnetism is related to quantum-mechanical "spin", and by being a dipole means that has both a north and a south pole.

However, it is theoretically possible to have magnetic monopole charges, various non-standard theories of physics proposed them, but unfortunately they have not been yet observed.